# php code that gather all form input and post it together

Tags: php

In my pages i have form that has several textarea, i need a method to gather all of the textareas in one email and then send it.

I need a method that i can add it to each page and do this automatically instead of referencing each textarea by name.

```
$email_body = "You have received a new message from the user $name. \r\n".
    "Here is the answer to the $step. \r\n $message \r\n Comments:$comments.\r\n".
```

Instead of `$message` i want all textareas.

Comment: StackOverflow is not the proper place for this question. We do not write your code for you. You need to do your own coding and if you aren't sure why something is not working as expected, post the code with an explanation of what you were expecting it to do, and what it is actually doing including all error messages. See [ask advice](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/ask-advice).

Comment: John - I think perhaps he just had no idea which direction to go in?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Let's re-write this whole answer.

HTML form:
[index.html]:

```
<html>
<body>
<form action="php_file.php" method="post">
<input type="text" name="field_1"/>
<input type="text" name="something_else"/>
<input type="text" name="third_field"/>
<input type="submit" name="submit" value="send!"/>
</form>
</body>
</html>
```

PHP file (processor):
[php_file.php:]

```
    $email_body = '';
    foreach($_POST as $key => $value)
    {
        $email_body .= "Field name: ".$key . "Value: ".$value."<br />";
    }

//send email with $email_body as the email body!
$to = "someone@example.com";
$subject = "Test mail";
$message = "Hello! This is a simple email message.";
$from = "website@stacksomething.com";
$headers = "From:" . $from;
mail($to,$subject,$email_body ,$headers);
echo "Email was sent!";
```

Comment: I have           <textarea rows="3" name="an[S1]" cols="60" style="margin-top: 0"></textarea>   where i need to enter <input name="input_field[]"/>    and thanks for help really i confused

Comment: Hi i'll add to my answer for you.

Comment: @Paul Best not to get this young buck into the habit of using spaces in names.  Use underscores.

As per the W3C spec: ID and NAME tokens must begin with a letter ([A-Za-z]) and may be followed by any number of letters, digits ([0-9]), hyphens ("-"), underscores ("_"), colons (":"), and periods (".").

Comment: oh yes completely missed that - i was just (badly) trying to point out that anything could be used. i'll change it (again). #musttryharder

Comment: Agreed it was me being wholly lazy in copying and pasting..